# What is a Bloch wall?

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

I have heard the term Bloch wall, used in relation to magnets. What is a Bloch wall?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. Images of iron filings and bar magnets don't appear to support what idea? That of Bloch walls? Why? You can think of Bloch walls as being the boundaries between the various magnetic domains of any ferromagnetic material, regardless of whether or not it has a net magnetization.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're trying to express. As for the magnetic force on a magnetic dipole, that's given by gradient of the magnetic field ( grad(m.B) where m is the magnetic dipole moment). Or perhaps you meant the magnetic torque on the dipole, which is m X B. ( http://www.physicsinsights.org/force_on_dipole_1.html )

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  It makes good sense to me.   Sorry about the way I originally asked the question, Ive edited out the nonsense.  It was in there because I had held some wrong views about what a Bloch walls  for sometime.

Comment: This is rather too broad for our format. Is there some specific aspect of [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_wall_(magnetism)#Bloch_wall) or its [main reference](http://www.science.uva.nl/research/cmp/qem/research_projects/domainwall.html) that you find confusing?

Comment: Thats understandable,  I cant think of anything else to ask right now.  Although this question has cleared up my gross misconception , I can see that it may not be  overly useful to this site in general as a learning tool for others,  Im  ok with it being deleted.  Im sorry about wasting every ones time.